# How to run scenario outline multiple time for list of data

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to run my scenario outline examples more than once with different set of data and data is dynamic for examples.

For eg:
I am having **java List** say **L** which contains values of country like USA, INDIA UK and so on.(which will generated dynamically) and I want to run my examples with set of data for eg:

```
Examples:
|Country| State| Region|
|USA    | ABC | DEF    |
|USA    | GHI | JKL    |
|USA    | MNO | PQR    |
```

Now I want above Examples will run for first USA and then for INDIA and so on(as per data in list)

I tried to make it run by using following

```
public class ABC {
    @test
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        for(String s: L){
            net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main.main(new String[] { "-g", "Path of Step Defs","Path of feature file" });
        }
    }
}
```

and running above class as "clean verify -Dit.test=Abc.java"

It is running fine for first data from list and report generated successfully, but it is not running for rest of data. Please suggest how can I achieve above part.

Thanks in advance.